# How to allow a third party to access your private testnet via their wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, testnets

So I set up a private eth testnet, and so far I was able to connect to it via my local wallet on the same machine. However I had some issues when connecting to the same local testnet via a different device, the RPC URL was not found along with the Chain ID. I've made sure that both are not being used by anyone else, and that they match up to my config code in the genesis json.

I'm very new at this and I'm not too sure what exactly I am doing, but I want to be able to access my private testnet via any device through any network. For example, I can keep the testnet running on my server from home and join it via my work network with another wallet application for example.

So far I've only got one node setup running with the genesis file, but I don't want to share the Genesis file with any other connected node. But if I do have to share it, is there any way to automate this process? By the third party attempting to connect and getting all the necessary information? I know you can do this with enodes, however is there a way to do it without manually finding the enode and then manually adding it into your ledger?

So to summarize, am I able to create a private testnet and not share the genesis file to review the status of an account through a different non-local connection? Or do I have to create a public testnet for that?

Comment: Would I require a boostrap node for this? If so, will I still need the Genesis.json to be on the third parties devices? 

For example, I'm trying to connect my phone to the network via Metamask, and there's no way I can write the same Genesis.json over on my phone. How would I connect in this case?

Comment: Would forwarding the port to an external IP work? And in the case that it does, would it bring about a security risk towards the network?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into BuildBear.io

https://medium.com/buildbear/win-web3-hackathons-using-buildbear-testnets-analytics-e67656093f9d

In BuildBear you can start your own private testnet, with your own explorer and faucet.